# How did the older Torah books look formatting wise?

Tags: torah-study, pentateuch-chumash

I'm wondering what the sort of evolution of the Torah's syntactic / punctuation structure looks like. Were the books always divided into "books" with titles like Genesis (in Hebrew of course)? Were they always numbered? When did the numbering come into play? Were the verses always written starting each on their own line, or was it just originally one mass of text? Etc. How generally did it evolve into the point where every verse is numbered and every book is titled.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Lance and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: If you have seen a Torah scroll, you'd notice that there are no vowels, verses, chapters or cantillation notes. Just paragraphs. What is clear is that there are 5 books. Although, from reading the Torah, itself, there is no mention that they should be divided this way. Chapters and verse numbering I understand were invented by the Greeks, much later. The Talmud gives different names for the 5 books than what we call them. And, when public Torah reading became important, the division of annual or triennial weekly portions got their names.

Comment: @DanF Chapters and verses were actually first invented by Medieval Christians and later a similar method was adopted by Jewish printers based on the trope.